# rails - API responses uncacheble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching, http-caching, faraday

I am developing a web app that communicates to the API. In order to boost up the performance I am trying to implement HTTP caching with Faraday.

At first, I've tried the standard `:memory_cache`:

```
@conn = Faraday.new(url: URL) do |builder|
    builder.use :http_cache, store: Rails.cache, logger: ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

development.rb:

```
...
if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
...
```

`tmp/caching-dev.txt` is in place so the caching is enabled.

But for each API request I was getting this:

```
HTTP Cache: [GET /parks] miss, uncacheable
```

And there's no explanation whatsoever as to what makes the response uncacheable. At least I couldn't find it.

Then I tried to switch to a custom memory cache:

```
class CustomCacheStore
  attr_accessor :store_hash

  def initialize
    @store_hash = Hash.new
  end

  def write(key, value)

  end

  def read(key)

  end

  def fetch(key)
    raise 'No block provided' unless block_given?

    result = read(key)

    if result.nil?
      result = yield
      write(key, result)
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Faraday config:

```
custom_store = CustomCacheStore.new
@conn = Faraday.new(url: URL) do |builder|
    builder.use FaradayMiddleware::Caching, store: custom_store, logger: ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

And still the same:

```
HTTP Cache: [GET /parks] miss, uncacheable
```

The API is also written in RoR and runs on nginx server with the following config:

```
upstream puma {   server unix:///{...}; }

server {   listen 8000 default_server deferred;

  root {...}
  access_log {...}
  error_log {...}

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;   }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;   location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;   }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 1500M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

---

Rails 5.1.6

Comment: How did you solve this?